# Laravel eloquent too slow with large amount of data

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, eloquent

I am using Laravel 7.0 and MySQL 5.7.

I am using Eloquent to fetch records from the database and when the database contains a large amount of data the response time becomes extremely slow.

A few examples are shown below:

`Movie::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->take(10)->get();` to get the first 10 results that match a search string.

`Movie::orderBy('rating', 'desc')->take(10)->get()` to get the 10 top rated movies.

`Person::has('acted')->orderBy('popularity', 'desc')->take(10)->get()` to get the 10 most popular actors.

When I use a test database of ~1000 records the response time is acceptable, but when I switch to the live database of ~500,000 records it's horrible.

Any suggestions on how to improve the performance are appreciated!

Comment: Are you expecting a few dozen results?  Or 500K results?

Comment: I am expecting a few dozen results and I use take(10) to get the first 10.

Comment: If there are less than 10 matching items, all 500K will be checked.  In that case, pagination will not help.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that. Is there something else that could help? This is a broader issue, not just with matching a search string, so your solution suggested below will not solve the problem. Another example would be ```Movie::orderBy('rating', 'desc')->take(10)->get();``` that fetches the top 10 rated movies.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Like: getting the raw query that is fired, and run this through `EXPLAIN` to check for missing indices?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone will need to see 500,000 results in a single page, you would need to break it into parts and **paginate** the results. You can also use **chunk**, or use the **cursor** method. Choose one that would fit your needs best.

If this is to be viewed by the user, then I would suggest to **paginate** the results. This way the user can go to the next page and the next page etc. Or click on "Load More" button to make a request to your API to load page 2 then page 3 etc.

If this is just to process data for manipulation or update values, I would suggest using **chunk** or **cursor**.

---

**To paginate:**

```
Movie::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(20);
```

*This will fetch 20 items per page.*

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/pagination#introduction

---

**To chunk:**

```
Movie::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->chunk(200, function ($movies) {
    foreach ($movies as $movie) {
        //
    }
});
```

*This will fetch 200 at a time then loop through them.*

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#chunking-results

---

**To use cursor method:**

```
foreach (Movie::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->cursor() as $movie) {
    //
}
```

*This will iterate through your database records using a cursor, which will only execute a single query.*

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#chunking-results

[Laracasts](https://laracasts.com) has a [10min video](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-6/episodes/1) of it explained in detail.

Comment: Indeed I am not displaying 500k results, I use take(10) to display only the first 10. This is for a search input that displays autocomplete results so paginating will not work. I read about chunking and cursor in the Laravel docs but I haven't found a way to use them in my case. My eloquent query is in a controller function that just returns the results, I am not doing any further processing so I am not sure why/how would I use the foreach loop to iterate through them.

Comment: I don't see the `->take(10)` in your code. But this should also be quick, unless, the 10th item is the 500,000th item in your database. It will only stop when it found the 10 items, so if there are only 9 matches in between 500k rows, it will go through all 500k rows.

Comment: As I commented above to @Rick James, this issue is not specific to this example. I need a way so that all queries (not just ```LIKE '%...'```) produce faster results with large volumes of data.

Comment: Then get your wording right and update your question.. you leave out a lot of detail then you debate back and forth about our answers.?

Comment: I apologise if I didn't make my question clear. Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated! I changed the description and added a few more details, hopefully it's more understandable now. If you can offer any more suggestions I'd be grateful!

Comment: @StephanosPapastylianou - I added a _different_ index for one of your other examples to my Answer.  If practical, show us the SQL for the queries; that will make it easier for me to give you specific advice.  _There is no single solution for how to speed up a "large" table_.

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE '%...'` is very inefficient.  Each row must be checked by scanning the text.

Much better is the use of

```
FULLTEXT INDEX(title)
```

and

```
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+$search')
```

(Sorry, I don't know how to turn that into Laravel.)

> Movie::orderBy('rating', 'desc')->take(10)->get()

That is probably helped by

```
INDEX(rating)
```

Comment: Respect for your MySQL skills! :)

Comment: I added another index for one of the newly added queries.  I don't know what the SQL equivalent to `has()`, so I don't know how to optimize it.